# Symfony 2 isClicked on submit buttons always returning FALSE

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to implement two submit buttons to my form. My form looks something like this.

Form:

```
public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('gateway', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Go to payment gateway',
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Save order',
    ));
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
}
```

Method `$form->get('save')->isClicked()` in controller always returning `FALSE` . It doesn't depend on which button I click in form, everytime returns `FALSE`.

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new OrderForm(null));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $values = $form->getData();

        $action = $form->get('save')->isClicked() ? 'front.order.success' : 'front.order.gateway';

        if ($action == 'front.order.success') {
            //save order
        } else if ($action == 'front.order.gateway') {
            //something else
        }

    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($action));
}
```

Have you any idea why? Thank you for answers.

Comment: Check $_POST data and ensure it has `save` variable when you click on `save` button.

Comment: How do you add your form fields to the twig template? Do you have any javascript running?

Comment: @VadimAshikhman : you are right. None of my submit button is in `$_POST`. Have you any idea why?

Comment: Ensure they are inside `<form>` tag

Comment: @VadimAshikhman : both submit buttons are inside `<form></form>` tags

Comment: @VadimAshikhman : this is content of my `$_POST` after submit one of the buttons http://pastebin.com/c8J0xfnz

Comment: Do you render the buttons manually? If so make sure they have the correct 'name' attributes to have them included in $_POST data.